# Trying get a minimum value for a function in loop while transferring values from list A to list B

Tags: python, loops, networkx

I am trying to get the normalized cut cost for a community detection question.
and below is my question:
there are two nodes list A and B; both length are 20
and there is a function in networkx, `nx.normalized_cut_size` which would return a value for normalized cut size base on the two lists above and the network graph (fixed in this question).

So I want to find the best combination for list A and B by transferring one node to another until get to the minimum normalized cut size value.
I am trying to use `.append` and `.remove` inside the loop, and I still think there is a better way. Can someone help?

```
largest = sorted(largest)## sort
lo = largest[:20]## lowest 50 % nodes
hi = largest[20:] ## highest 50% nodes

for i in lo:
    hi.append(i)
    lo.remove(i)
    print nx.normalized_cut_size(Gc,hi,lo)/2
```

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: largest = sorted(largest)## sort
lo = largest[:20]## lowest 50 % nodes
hi = largest[20:] ## highest 50% nodes 
for i in lo:
    hi.append(i)
    lo.remove(i)
    print nx.normalized_cut_size(Gc,hi,lo)/2

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code as properly formatted text

Comment: When you say "best combination"  what do you mean?  It's not clear that your code will give what you want.

Comment: the whole dataset is the 'largest' and when we input the different hi and lo into normialized_cut_size function ,it would return different values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go through all the transferring: just use the slices you want:

```
for i in range(20):
    print nx.normalized_cut_size(Gc, largest[20-i:], largest[:20-i])
```

I'll leave the off-by-one and boundary problems for you to check.

---

Minimum of the sequence: wrap them in a list comprehension and apply `min` to the list.

```
print min([ nx.normalized_cut_size(Gc, largest[20-i:], largest[:20-i])
             for i in range(20) ])
```

Comment: Prune, thank you, your code works,  but it is just 20 different combination of hi and lo lists as well as  the returned value, I am struggled to find the minimum value cross all the possible combinations. Thanks anyway

Comment: Finding the minimum of a sequence is covered in many, many places.